# Does the pagelinks table contains redirects?

Tags: sql, database, mediawiki

I want to count how many inbound links each MediaWiki page have. I want to know if I need to consider redirects in `pagelinks` table or not.

MediaWiki database have `pagelinks` table which have all links included. This table have three attributes `'pl_from'`, `'pl_namespace'` and `'pl_title'`. I want to extract links from `pagelinks.sql` file from MediaWiki database dump.

Do you know if `'pl_from'` can have id of redirect page and `'pl_title'` can have redirect title?

Comment: Wikipedia is one implementation that **uses** MediaWiki, but they are not interchangeable. I've retagged your question.

Answer (score 0):

For the purposes of `pagelinks`, redirects are treated as normal pages.

So, for example, if you have a redirect page with the following code:

```
#REDIRECT [[Some page]]

[[Another link]]
```

Then there will be two entries for this page as `pl_from`: one for `Some page` and another for `Another link`. What this means is that a redirect will always have a row for its target page, but it can also have other rows.

And `pl_title` contains the title of a linked page based on the code of the page. So, if there is a page with a link to a redirect, the title of that redirect will appear as `pl_title`.